# Kubectl wait for one pod of a statefulset to be READY?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

To wait for a certain pod to be completed the command is

`kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/pod-name`

Similarly I want to wait for any one pod in the statefulset to be ready. I tried the command below which did not work,

`kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready statefulset/statefulset-name`

What should the command options look like?

Comment: there is already one issue there on official kubernetes repo regarding using wait with `statefulsets` : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79606

Comment: @agirlwithnoname did Harsh comment solved your problem? do you need further help to set up the wait function for your stateful set using oke-py ? let me know.

Comment: @willrof could you let me know the same !

Comment: I found this to be helpful https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79606#issuecomment-655282134

Answer (score 8):

I used following and it works for me

```
kubectl wait -l statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=activemq-0 --for=condition=ready pod --timeout=-1s
```

Answer (score 7):

```
kubectl rollout status --watch --timeout=600s statefulset/name-of-statefulset
```

from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79606#issuecomment-779779928

Comment: Thanks this works perfect:
```Waiting for 3 pods to be ready...```
```Waiting for 2 pods to be ready...```
```Waiting for 1 pods to be ready...```
```partitioned roll out complete: 3 new pods have been updated...```

Comment: Fails due to `error: rollout status is only available for RollingUpdate strategy type` with `kubectl` 1.28.5.